# Is it possible to programmatically scroll to a child of on appbarlayout?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
<AppBarLayout>
<CollapsingToolbarLayout>
<Toolbar/>
</CollapsingToolbarLayout>
<View1/>
<View2/>
<View3/>
</AppBarLayout>
<RecyclerView/>(app_bar_scrolling_behavior)
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to programatically scroll to view3 on some action to an item in recyclerview.Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to acheive this using the below code snippet by using value animator.
`

```
recyclerview.scrollToPosition(0)
val params = appbar.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams
val behavior = params.behavior as AppBarLayout.Behavior?
if (behavior != null) {
  val valueAnimator: ValueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt()
  valueAnimator.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
  valueAnimator.addUpdateListener { animation ->
    behavior.topAndBottomOffset = (animation.animatedValue as Int)
    appBar.requestLayout()
  }
  valueAnimator.setIntValues(
    0, -appbar.totalScrollRange + view3.root.measuredHeight
  )
  valueAnimator.duration = 50
  valueAnimator.start()
}
```

`